# Power BI, hide tabs based on role level security

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

Is there a way to hide a tab based on role level security?
I have been able to lock the dataset but the tab is still visible.
The users who are not allocated access to the dataset are asking why there is no data. It would be great to hide the tab completely.

I am designing in power desktop and publishing the reports for the users to view on the BI service premium capacity.

Would greatly appreciate your help. Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Row Level Security only applies to the data, being shown, it cannot show or hide tabs based on the users. Both the Power BI Service and Power BI Premium, can't show hide the tabs based on any user verification methods. I would have a look at creating an App, that way you should be able to hide the data bar on the right, and they will only get the filters options

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. Yes I agree that it only applies to data. I have applied it to the App but as users cannot see the data, they are asking why? For now I have just added a label to show it is restricted. Would be nice if there was a work around to how hide the tab. Thank you for response. Will post here if I find a way.